# Scrolling is disabled but still works on mobiles

Tags: mobile, scroll, responsive-design

I’m having some trouble with my website, and I can’t get around it.

I’m trying to have my home page fixed, not scrollable. Which is currently working on desktops but not on mobiles. I checked the margins, everything seems fine.

Even though my code is as follow, for this specific page:

```
html, body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
        }
```

I can’t get this straight. Any help would be highly appreciated.

The website is http://92-blue.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try not using 100 vh , on the mobile version. 100 vh displays the entire screen vertically for any device. When you are viewing it with the 100vh it will take into account the entire phone screen that is why it is scroll able, it gets moved down because of the url bar.

Comment: Works perfectly now, thank you so much!
Although I might be bugging but it seems like the text blocks aren't vertically aligned even though they should be. Are both the bottom and top bars (on iPhones) are messing up with alignment?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, can you elaborate. It seems to be working fine on my LG G5.